# C++ error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token

Tags: c++

I am following an SDL tutorial and have run across a problem. When I compile my program, it gives the errors

```
/home/cevent.h 9 error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token
/home/cevent.cpp 5 error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token
```

My code is as follows:

The Header file

```
//cevent.h
#ifndef CEVENT_H
#define CEVENT_H

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

class CEvent {
public:
    CEvent();
    virtual -CEvent();
    void onEvent(SDL_Event *event);
    virtual void onExit();
    //and various other virtual method declarations
};

#endif // CEVENT_H
```

And the source file

```
//cevent.cpp
#include "cevent.h"

CEvent::CEvent() {}

CEvent::-CEvent() {}

void CEvent::onEvent(SDL_Event *event) {
    switch(event->type) {
        //some code for handling events
    }
}
//some temporarily empty method definitions
```

I have dug through multiple online solutions to similar problems, but i can neither find one that satisfies my problem nor work out the solution based on what i have read.

Comment: You should always remove your filepath from your post because it might leak personal info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to C++ destructor starts with `~` not `-`. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t4fe76c.aspx)

update

```
virtual -CEvent();
```

to

```
virtual ~CEvent();
//      ^
```

Comment: Oh... Well, that confirms that I should use a bigger monitor whilst trying to learn new things.

Answer (score 3):

```
virtual -CEvent();
```

Should be

```
virtual ~CEvent();
        ^^^ a tilde
```